# Org mode agenda: Reuse code in block agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have an org-agenda-custom-commands like so:

```
("u" "Unscheduled TODO"
           todo ""
           ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nUnscheduled TODO")
           (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if
                                              'scheduled 'deadline 'timestamp
                                              'todo '("BACKBURNER")))))
```

I would like to reuse the todo part of this agenda view in other block agenda views. So for instance defining an `unscheduled-todo` list for reuse (pseudocode, not working):

```
(setq unscheduled-todo '((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nUnscheduled TODO")
                           (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if
                                                       'scheduled 'deadline 'timestamp
                                                       'todo '("BACKBURNER")))))
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("u" "Unscheduled TODO"
            (todo "" unscheduled-todo))
          ("c" "Complete View"
            ((agenda "")
             (todo "" unscheduled-todo))))
```

How do I get the above code to work? I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how and when the code and lists are getting evaluated. I've tried a number of configurations of ' and () in both `setq` and `org-agenda-custom-commands`, along with `append` to create lists, but I'd also like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: You probably need to define `unscheduled-todo` as a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html#Macros) which expands to the "right" thing and then use it in the setting of `org-agenda-custom-commands` with a backquote and comma (see [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote)).

Comment: @Rorschach: Indeed. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation along the lines of my comment (although I think you really don't need a macro here: a function does just as well or better):

```el
(defun unscheduled-todo ()
    '((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nUnscheduled TODO")
      (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if
                                  'scheduled 'deadline 'timestamp
                                  'todo '("BACKBURNER")))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      ; N.B. the character following this comment is a *backquote* 
      ; (the key to the left of the 1 key on a standard US keyboard);
      ; it is *NOT* a quote (the key to the left of the ENTER key
      ; on a standard US keyboard).
      `(("u" "Unscheduled TODO"
         todo "" ,(unscheduled-todo))
        ("c" "Complete View"
            ((agenda "")
             (todo "" ,(unscheduled-todo))))))
```

I hope it's correct now (I had to fix it a couple of bugs) but it's only lightly tested.

Note that this uses the [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) mechanism to quote most of the value in the
`setq` of `org-agenda-custom-commands` while allowing the evaluation of the call to the macro using the comma mechanism.

EDIT: As @Rorschach points out in a (now deleted) comment, I'm overcomplicating things. You still need backquote and comma, but you can use the variable you defined:

```el
(setq unscheduled-todo
    '((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nUnscheduled TODO")
      (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if
                                  'scheduled 'deadline 'timestamp
                                  'todo '("BACKBURNER")))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      ; N.B. the character following this comment is a *backquote* 
      ; (the key to the left of the 1 key on a standard US keyboard);
      ; it is *NOT* a quote (the key to the left of the ENTER key
      ; on a standard US keyboard).
      `(("u" "Unscheduled TODO"
         todo "" ,unscheduled-todo)
        ("c" "Complete View"
            ((agenda "")
             (todo "" ,unscheduled-todo)))))
```

The backquote/comma mechanism allows the evaluation of a spliced-in variable just as well as it allows the evaluation of a spliced-in function call.